# Basic C pointer question

Tags: c, pointers

It has been a while since I last programmed C, seems I have forgotten everything
in the meantime... I have a very simple pointer question. Assuming that I have
a function that computes a sum through loop iteration. Not only should this function
return the loop counter but also the sum it computed. Since I can just return one
value I assume the best I could do for the sum is declaring a pointer. Can I do that like this:

```
   int loop_function(int* sum)
   {
    int len = 10; 

    for(j = 0; j < len; j++) 
    {
      sum += j;
    }

   return(j);
   }   

   ....


   int sum = 0;
   loop_function(&sum);
   printf("Sum is: %d", sum);
```

Or do I need to define an extra variable that points to sum which I pass then to the function?

Many thanks,
Marcus

Comment: There's nothing that indicates that this is remotely related to C++, so I removed the C++ tag.

Comment: @Nikko it would work the same in both.

Comment: It would work, but in C++ you'd use a reference.  There are cases when you'd want pointers like this, but in a case where *sum* is never null, always used, and you aren't exporting the function to another language...  use a reference.

Comment: Thanks for all our comments, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 17):

What you have is correct except for this line:

```
sum += j;
```

Since `sum` is a pointer, this increments *the address contained in the pointer* by `j`, which isn't what you want. You want to increment the *value pointed to by the pointer* by `j`, which is done by applying the dereference operator `*` to the pointer first, like this:

```
*sum += j;
```

Also, you need to define `j` somewhere in there, but I imagine you know that and it's just an oversight.

Answer (score 9):

Write

```
*sum += j;
```

What you are doing is incrementing the pointer (Probably not what you wanted)

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
*sum += j;
```

so you increment the *value pointed to* instead of the local pointer variable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create extra variable but in the loop you need to do

```
 *sum += j
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write *sum + = j;

This suffices

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare a simple struct to hold the two values, then pass in a pointer to an instance of that structure.  That way you could manipulate both variables and they'd retain their values after the function returns.

```
struct loop_sum_struct {
    int loop_ctr;
    int sum;
} loop_sum;

loop_function(&loop_sum);

void loop_function(loop_sum_struct *s) {
    int len = 10;
    for(s->loop_ctr = 0; s->loop_ctr loop_ctr++) {
        s->sum += s->loop_ctr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this ?

As you are already returning int. So, another way is to just change the signature to

> int loop_function(int sum)

and at the time of calling

> int sum = 0;
>
> ...
>
> sum = loop_function(sum);

Comment: The OP is trying to return two things from one function:  the loop counter, and the sum.  In C, this typically means passing in a pointer and modifying what it points to.

Comment: Ah, true !
I just looked at the definition only in the OP which is not storing the return value anywhere but I see your point now. Thanks !